# Cannot connect vb with database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I already downloaded the connector and installed it but it doesn't appeared in .Net tab. So what should I do now?

first warning:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'MySql.Data.MysqlClient' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

second warning:

> This primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL"could not be resolved because it has as indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" thanthe version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your target version of the .NET framework to .NET 4.0 in your project properties.  That should resolve both warnings because it will clear the second warning which will make the referenced assembly jive with the imported namespace.

[image]

[image]